# The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq to Entities query of the following form:

```
var x = from a in SomeData
    where ... some conditions ...
    select new MyType
    {
        Property = a.Property,
        ChildCollection = from b in a.Children
                        select new MyChildType
                        {
                            SomeProperty = b.Property,
                            AnotherProperty = b.AnotherProperty
                        }
    };

var y = from a in SomeData
    where ... some other conditions ...
    select new MyType
    {
        Property = a.Property,
        ChildCollection = from b in a.Children
                        select new MyChildType
                        {
                            SomeProperty = b.Property,
                            AnotherProperty = b.AnotherProperty
                        }
    };

var results = x.Concat(y);
```

(This is a simplified example - the 'where' and 'select' clauses are more complex than shown here.  I'm using separate queries statements as creating a single combined one is just too complicated, has too many conditionals and takes an age to compile)

Compiles fine, but fails at execution with the exception:

```
"The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'
```

Note, I am trying to project into a nested typed structure.  If I call .ToList() on x and y prior to the Concat() it works fine.  As a further point, one of my properties is an enum, but I am assigning to it using an integer wrapper property.

Is there a way I can do what I want to do without having to pull all the data into memory?  Or is it the enum causing the failure?

Thanks,

T

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
 var results = x.Union(y);
```

?

Tiz

or

```
var x = (from a in SomeData
where ... some conditions ...
select new MyType
{
    Property = a.Property,
    ChildCollection = (from b in a.Children
                    select new MyChildType
                    {
                        SomeProperty = b.Property,
                        AnotherProperty = b.AnotherProperty
                    }).ToArray() //or DefaultIfEmpty
}).Concat(
from a in SomeData
where ... some other conditions ...
select new MyType
{
    Property = a.Property,
    ChildCollection = (from b in a.Children
                    select new MyChildType
                    {
                        SomeProperty = b.Property,
                        AnotherProperty = b.AnotherProperty
                    }).ToArray() //or DefaultIfEmpty
});
```

Comment: Just tried the second of these and seems to behave exactly the same as first, i.e. doesn't work as I hoped (see my comment on @Arion's post.

Comment: ...which has now been deleted.  Anyway, don't mind using Union as the result sets should be distinct anyway, but I then get the exception "The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument." which I believe is because Distinct can't handle the nested collection.

Comment: If Empty? How is it behavior?

Comment: If what's empty?  If I comment out the projection of the ChildCollection element it works fine.  Thanks for looking at this by the way :-)

Comment: What is type of MyType.ChildCollection Maybe IEnumerable(of MyChildType) ??

Comment: Yes, sorry should have made that clear.  ChildCollection is of type IEnumerable<MyChildType>.  I've tried populating it in a number of ways without success.  I'm pretty sure empty values aren't the issue here but the fact that ChildCollection is not a simple type.

Comment: if you select an anonymous type instead of a new object? EX:              from b in a.Children
                    select SomeProperty = b.Property, AnotherProperty = b.AnotherProperty

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar problem while trying to concatenate or union multi sets  of navigation properties into single IEnumerable, here is the code sample :

```
var requiredDocuments =                
                 (from x in db.RequestTypes where (some condition) select x.RequiredDocuments)
                 .SelectMany(r => r).ToList<DataModel.RequiredDocument>()
                 .Concat(
                 (from c in db.Categories where (some condition) select c.RequiredDocuments)
                 .SelectMany(r => r).ToList<DataModel.RequiredDocument>()
                 )
                 .Concat(
                 (from f in db.Fields where (some condition) select f.RequiredDocuments)
                 .SelectMany(r => r).ToList<DataModel.RequiredDocument>()
                );
```

Comment: Is this your problematic bit of code or a working one?

Comment: as this calls ToList before executing the Concat this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I have run into the same problem several times.  The bottom line is, doing unions with nested projections is not supported and if you need to do that, you'll have to materialize the results with ToList first.